# How to send JSON from server-side (nodejs) to client-side with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, rest, express

I've created a Node.js/express server to GET call API. The API returns a json data. How do I send the JSON I've received to my local javascript (client-server)? I'd like to grab this JSON, send to my local client (with an ajax call if this is the option), loop through it and append it to my DOM!

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require("request");

let name, value, bodyData;

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.example.com/data1',
  qs: 
   { 
     valueType: 'MAXIMUM'
   },
  headers: 
   { 
     authorization: 'ABC123456',
     accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  bodyData = body;

});


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', {data: bodyData});
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Items</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="itemsList">
    <h2>List of available items:  </h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost:3000/",
       contentType: "application/json"
     }).done(function(data){
          for(var i =1; i<= 10; i++){
          $('#itemsList').append('<div id="r'+ i +'"></div>')
          }
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `data` is an array then you should write loop in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "http://localhost:3000/",
       contentType: "application/json"
     }).done(function(data){
          for(var i =1; i<data.length; i++){
          $('#itemsList').append('<div id="r'+ data[i] +'">'+data[i]+'</div>')
          }
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get('/', (request, response)=>{
  response.json({
    message: 'Hello world!',
    arrayText: ['message1', 'message2']
  }):
});
```